# Prevent clang-format from breaking function pointer definitions

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

Clang-format changes this:

```
HANDLE (*get)();
```

to:

```
HANDLE(*get)
();
```

How can we prevent that?
Note that if we have `Handle`, `hANDLE`, or anything else that is not all in caps, this formatting is not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you have `ColumnLimit: 0`. With any other value for `ColumnLimit`, the parentheses are kept on the same line. Note that the pre-defined style `WebKit` sets `ColumnLimit: 0`, so maybe you are using the `WebKit` style. Your workaround would be to set `ColumnLimit` to some reasonable non-zero value.

Also interesting, once the parentheses are on a separate line, none of the `clang-format` style options will force them to get put back on the first line, even if you set `ColumnLimit` to something non-zero.

I think this is a `clang-format` defect.

Comment: It works. But I don't understand the difference between HANDLE and other ones like Handle, handle,... Maybe it is a clang-format bug as you thought.

Comment: As an aside I'm using LLVM style and this sets ColumnLimit to 0 too.

Comment: No, llvm style has ColumnLimit set to 80. At least it does with clang-format 6.0.0 that I'm using on Ubuntu.