# Clang format: prevent break before indexing

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm having a formatting issue with the following (code edited for macro to be upper case, added a mixed case version as well)-

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    MACRO_ARRAY_CALL(param)[i] = MACRO_ARRAY_CALL(param2)[i];
    Macro_array_call(param)[i] = Macro_array_call(param2)[i];
}
```

where `macro_array_call` accesses an array of length 3 belong to param (which is a struct object). For some reason, my clang format file reformats this to

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    MACRO_ARRAY_CALL(param)
    [i] = MACRO_ARRAY_CALL(param2)[i];
    Macro_array_call(param)[i] = Macro_array_call(param2)[i];
}
```

I am not seeing anything in clang format that indicates a break would happen prior to something like this. Interestingly, this happens only when the macro is fully capitalized. I'm not seeing a similar behaviour elsewhere so far. If the same macro is a combination of lower and uppercase or only lowercase, this does not happen.

This is my clang format file. Is there something I need to modify to get the correct behaviour?

```
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  Microsoft
AccessModifierOffset: -2
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   Align
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: true
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  BeforeWhile:     true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
DeriveLineEnding: true
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentCaseBlocks: false
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: AfterHash
IndentExternBlock: AfterExternBlock
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
InsertTrailingCommas: None
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCBreakBeforeNestedBlockParam: true
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 100000
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 0
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    false
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Latest
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        4
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - STRINGIZE
  - PP_STRINGIZE
  - BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE
 
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: AllDefinitions
ColumnLimit:     0
...
```

Edit: braces for the for loop

Comment: is macro_array_call a macro? Try rewriting it as a function template so you can end the line with a `;`. Macros are not really a good thing to have anyway so can you show what the macro does? (if there is no string concatenation rewrite to a function should be possible). And I would advice you to add a scope to your for loop as well

Comment: It is an existing codebase with this kind of thing in a lot of different places. It is not one-off. And yes, the call is a macro. The problem seems to happen only when the macro is a fully capitalized. I found a related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194848/prevent-clang-format-from-breaking-function-pointer-definitions) with the same issue but is not helpful here.

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works well. Please post a [mcve] - the shown code cannot be formatted as it's shown, because the third line is out of the loop scope.

Comment: That is a minimum reproducible example, except for the brackets that I forgot to add during editing. Fixed that as well now. My clang format file is also here. Try [clang format playground](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/). Let all the settings be default. Use ColumnLimit = 0

Comment: @273K If you are able to get it to work, please share your format file. Mine refuses to work.

Comment: Confirmed with using `ColumnLimit: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few experiments, I have found a solution:

```
WhitespaceSensitiveMacros:
  - MACRO_ARRAY_CALL
```

I'm not sure if it fixes the already formatted code, but it does not corrupt the manual formatting at least. I will update my answer if I find a better solution.

Comment: Wasn't around to check earlier. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Found something that helps. The problem here seems to be that a fully capitalized macro is being broken into multiple lines for no apparent reason.

Add this as a TypenameMacro (available from clang format 9) and the problem no longer presents.